# Oracle SQL: dummy variable from 2 data sets

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two data tables.  They both have an employee id column and a sales quarter column, in addition to lots of other columns.  The first, which ill call "Roster", has one row per employee per sales quarter.  The second has multiple rows per employee per quarter, with each row being a type of sale made, a column called "salestype" and this second table called "QuarterlySales".  Basically, I need to return a number of columns from the first table, but I also need a dummy variable indicating if the employee made a sales type of "cold call".

I tried an if statement but didnt work.

```
select employeeid, quarter, variablea, variableb, ....., 
if saletype = 'cold call' then 1 else 0 end as ColdCall
from Roster r
left join quarterly sales q
on r.employeeid = q.employeeid
and r.quarter = q.quarter
where blah blah blah conditions;
```

Im sure my approach is wrong.  I welcome any help.

Comment: You could replace the "if" in your second line by "case when" and try again. If this doesn't help, I think you should provide some sample data, the expected result and your real query.

Comment: Thanks @JonasMetzler! That did the trick.  I tried that at first before the if statement but my joins were incorrect. I fixed those and it worked, it appears.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @dbwhite64 for giving feedback. Just added this as answer to make it possible to close this question. Please accept it and have a nice weekend.

Comment: You too, Jonas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If clauses are not possible in this way, you need a case when instead:

```
...CASE WHEN saletype = 'cold call' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ColdCall...
```